# Call a function on multiple objects dynamically

Tags: python

I wonder if it is possible to dynamically call a function on multiple objects. For example:

```
class Obj:
    def Foo():
        print("foo")

    def Bar():
        print("bar")

a = Obj()
b = Obj()

def execute(objects, func):
    # execute func on both a & b

execute([a, b], Obj.Foo)
execute([a, b], Obj.Bar)
```

Note: functions cannot be called like `func(obj)`, and need to be called like this: `obj.func()`

Comment: Sure, assuming they're instance methods of the `Obj` class (which take a `self` parameter), you'd simply invoke `Obj.Foo(a)` or `Obj.Foo(b)`.

Comment: @PaulM. What if cannot be called like this:

`func(obj)`
and need to be called like this

`obj.func()`

Comment: The question makes no sense now. You cannot call a.Obj.func.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a `for` loop.

```
def execute(objects, func):
    for obj in objects:
        func(obj)
```

This is assuming you don't care about the result of the functions, only the side effects. If you want a list of the results, you can use a list comprehension.

```
def execute(objects, func):
    return [func(obj) for obj in objects]
```

Comment: The functions need to be called from an instance (cannot be `func(obj)`, needs to be `obj.func()`

Comment: No, they do not. You're missing the `self` argument in the OP when you declare the functions, but if you declare them correctly, then this syntax will work just fine.

Comment: The library that I am using (web3.py) does not support direct calls to methods, and they need to be called from a module instance. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are probably more appropriate, but you might consider:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

```
# func will be called with one parameter.
list(map(func, objects))
```

To illustrate (assuming the OP's code has self added as a parameter to Foo, Bar):

```
list(map(Obj.Foo, [a, b]))
foo
foo
[None, None]
```

Or, in 3.5 and beyond:

```
*map(Obj.Foo, [a, b]),
```

Comment: The functions need to be called from an instance (cannot be `func(obj)`, needs to be `obj.func()`

Comment: @Pierre They can be called almost exactly the way the OP asked:
list(map(Obj.Foo, [a, b]))
foo
foo
[None, None]

Comment: The library I am using, web3.py, does not support direct calls to methods, and they must be called from a module instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import methodcaller

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        
    def open_door(self):
        print(f'{self.name} opens the door.')
    
    def greet(self, greeting):
        print(f'{self.name} says {greeting}!')
        
p1 = Person('Josh', 35)
p2 = Person('Nina', 33)
p3 = Person('Michael', 35)
p4 = Person('Krystin', 34)
people = p1, p2, p3, p4

instructions = [
    methodcaller('open_door'),
    methodcaller('greet', 'Hello'),
]
[[step(p) for step in instructions] for p in people]
```

Output:

```
Josh opens the door.
Josh says Hello!
Nina opens the door.
Nina says Hello!
Michael opens the door.
Michael says Hello!
Krystin opens the door.
Krystin says Hello!
```